# Delete android add from firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

Is there a way to delete an android app (created for a mistake) from the firebase console? It seems you can only add apps, not remove them

Thanks

Comment: Goto Apps, select settings of application which is added mistakenly, and click on Remove application in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, go to Project settings on the firebase console, go to the end of page and you have Delete option, or Remove Option.

http://prntscr.com/o9i0ch the settings tab

http://prntscr.com/o9i0qk remove/delete section

Answer (score 1):

> It seems you can only add apps, not remove them

You can also remove an app. You can achieve this by selectig the the app, go to `Project settings`:

[image]

And at the bottom of your page you have a button named `Remove this app`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the delete option this is super simple to do.

[image]